# How to configure to datasource one for Mongo database the other for H2 database with spring-boot?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, h2

How to configure two datasource one for Mongo database the other for H2 database?
This is my code for configure mongo repository but DataSource object it a javax.sql.DataSource.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "domainEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "domainTransactionManager", basePackageClasses = {CustomerRepositoryMongo.class})
public class CustomerConfigMongo {

@Bean
@Primary
PlatformTransactionManager domainTransactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(domainEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
}

@Bean
@Primary
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean domainEntityManagerFactory() {

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    factoryBean.setDataSource(domainDataSource());
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(Customer.class.getPackage().getName());
    return factoryBean;
}

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.data.mongodb")
DataSource domainDataSource() {
    DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();;
    return dataSource;
}

}
```

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot, why don't let it handle all that boilerplate for you? MongoDB does not require a datasource at all. Why don't you let [spring boot does the work for you](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-mongodb) and then you can tune it once it works?

Comment: Because if I let spring-boot do that. Sprint-boot will ignore h2 datasource

Comment: I am not sure what "ignore H2 datasource" means. If you want us to help, you'll have to provide more details. But you should not create a datasource for mongo, it doesn't use that at all.